# What is the precise location of the grid points/voxels in a Gaussian .cube file?

Tags: software, gaussian

Assume that we have a cube file that contains `Ni * Nj * Nk` points, and an origin at `0, 0, 0`, where are the data points actually located?

Let's say the grid spacing along each direction is `di, dj, dk` in crystal coordinates (so `di = 1 / (Ni - 1)`).

Are the data points located at `0, di, 2 * di, ..., ... Nx * di` or `0.5 * di, 1.5 * di, ..., (Nx + 0.5) * di` (and correspondingly for other axes)? Meaning, is the sampled data **at** the origin and corresponding gridpoints, or are they **between** the gridpoints, similar to a mean value for **voxels**?

**References** (that may be useful, but don't answer the question above definitively):

1. http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/cube/ A good exposition about the cube file format.
2. https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/blob/master/ase/io/cube.py#L69 ASE's cube file reader.
3. https://h5cube-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cubeformat.html Another attempt at the specs of the cube file format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The canonical source is probably [Gaussian's user documentation](https://gaussian.com/cubegen/) according to which the cube file defines an initial point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, as well as three step directions $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$ and the corresponding number of steps $N_i$ for $i=1,2,3$. The data are computed *at* the gridpoints, since averaging would make grid data evaluation much more costly, and at the limit of an infinitely fine grid the two results coincide.